# How do I Disable Windows 10 Password Hint?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, password-management

When I first created my user account on Windows 10, I was forced to add a password hint as well.

I have tried to remove the password hint, through the Windows 10 settings, but I have been unable to do so.

How can I disable the password hint?

Comment: You are never forced to do anything, a password hint isn't required but if it's set the best method to get rid of it is to create a new user that doesn't have one set and transfer your files to that new profile

Comment: @Ramhound I am literally unable to not put anything for the password hint.

Comment: Password hint cannot be used to recover or determine the password, or the value, doesn't have to be meaningful

Comment: While I agree with @Ramhound that it is no problem to have the hint on, you can just type in there something totally irrelevant that will never give out your pass. There is actually 2 ways to get rid of it. See my answer.

Comment: I always just put "No hints".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1) Turn your local account into Live ID account.  It won't have password hint.

or

2) You can turn it off by changing your password in User Accounts in desktop Control Panel. (***But if you do this way, you will lose all EFS-encrypted files, personal certificates, and stored passwords for Web sites or network resources.***)

- In desktop **Control Panel**, click on **User Accounts**
- Click on **Manage another account**
- Click on account you want to change
- Click on **change the password**
- Enter a new password Leave password hint blank
- Click on **Change password**.

**Source:** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/96899eb4-b04d-40d1-ae5d-60d163c770a8/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-password-hints

Comment: Why do you lose all encrypted files, certificates & passwords just because you don't want a password hint?

Comment: Also, I'm not able to leave the password hint blank. I believe I got Windows 10 in 2017 or later, so this may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You must be logged in as Administrator or any other account with admin rights in order to modify account settings.

Just right click on Start Menu, select Run and type: `control userpasswords2`

That will open the User Accounts console, then goto Advanced tab, click on Advanced button, open Users folders, select the account you need to modify or delete the hint in this case, rigth click on it, choose Set password, click on Proceed button: type in your current password or whatever you want it to be, OK > OK and that's all, you're good to go, logout or lock your session (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Next time when asked for credentials there will be no hint no more.